# What types can be put in AFNetworking POST parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

Can anyone explain what type I can put in my Dictionary for POST request. Can I put anything else from `NSString`?

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
self.manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[self.manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
self.manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [self.manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

double addTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000;

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [SOUser sharedManager].Id, @"id",
                            [SOUser sharedManager].Token, @"token",
                            @25, @"name",
                            @"I am testing Ican", @"description",
                            @"progress", @"status",
                            @"public_g", @"privacy",
                            addTime, @"addtime",
                            addTime, @"edittime",
                            @"ddddd", @"image",
                            @"1419424397", @"endtime", nil];

NSLog(@"%@", parameters);

[self.manager POST:@"api/goal/"
        parameters:parameters
           success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

           }];
```

Can I put in `double`? Or `NSArray` with `double`?

Comment: You should be able to put any data that can be encoded as JSON since you specify a JSON serializer.

Comment: @rmaddy
NSArray with double i can put for this POST?

Comment: You need to wrap the `double` in `NSNumber` of course. Did you try what you want? It would be faster than waiting for an answer.

Comment: @rmaddy
I asked and then after few minutes try)thank you, i want to know it for 100%

Comment: @СергейОлейнич If you look at `AFURLRequestSerialization.m`, you can see precisely what AFNetworking is doing with `AFJSONRequestSerializer` (namely just calling `NSJSONSerialization`). And you can refer to the `NSJSONSerialization` documentation for information about what can be safely encoded into JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `AFJSONRequestSerializer`, you are constrained by the limitations of `NSJSONSerialization`, whose documentation says:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> - The top level object is an `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.
> - All objects are instances of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`.
> - All dictionary keys are instances of `NSString`.
> - Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
>
> Other rules may apply. Calling `isValidJSONObject:` or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be converted to JSON data.

So wrap your `double` in a `NSNumber`, and you can include it in the dictionary you pass for `parameters`.

Answer (score -1):

infact you can use anything as POST parameters, but in NSDictionary you are except to use NSString as key and any object as value.

this is form apple document

`In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string (see “Key-Value Coding Fundamentals”).`

if u don't use NSString as a key the NSDictionary may error

Comment: The documentation you quote doesn't really apply to the question.